# After Joomla update from 3.5.1. to 3.6.0 I get the following error: JLIB_CLIENT_ERROR_JFTP_APPEND_BAD_RESPONSE

Tags: php, joomla, updates

When I Update my current Joomla from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0 the update process starts as expected. But at the end the browser switches to a blank white site. Afterwards when i call the admininstration or the frontend i get following error message: `JLIB_CLIENT_ERROR_JFTP_APPEND_BAD_RESPONSE`

Anybody able to help me with this? When i check the apache error.log, nothing is shown.

Thanks in advance
René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i found right now is the following:

- I restored a backup of the entire site with the data of yesterday.
- Then I entered the administration panel
- Switched to configuration and server and disabled the FTP-Layer (which was enabled before)
- Now i called the component "Joomla Update"
- I started the installation process für 3.6.0
- The system finished the process wihtouht problems

So my opinion is to be very careffully with the update when the ftp-layer is switched on.